# error while accessing a resource in restful architecture

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am trying to access a resource by the url http://localhost:5252/test/api/values/5 using express iis as server but I get the following error in the xml response.

```
   <Error>
    <Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
    </Error>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
  // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
```

Comment: whats the header of your controller look like? Did you add any authorization mechanism to your api?

Comment: Yep, make sure you don't have any `[Authorize]` attributes on your controller, or globally. Otherwise, you will need to send a cookie along with the request to authorize it.

Comment: thank you, I get now the response from the web service by simply deleting [Authorize]